# What does a String Property GET return?

Tags: c#, string, theory

In C#

Assume I have the following:

```
public String whatHappens{ get; set; }
```

Assume the property has been initialized and set.

Then down here I call

```
Console.WriteLine(whatHappens);
```

Does the GET call return a string object and the Console.WriteLine call ToString() 
OR
Does the GET call in turn call the ToString() method within the string class and return a string.

This is not a school question it's an argument my co-worker and I are having.

Comment: A reference to a string object is returned by the property getter, and the overload of Console.WriteLine() which takes a string is called, and `ToString()` is NOT called at all. (Note that the compiler generates a hidden string field for the class to implement an automatic string property such as the one you specified, and it is a reference to that hidden string field that is returned from the getter.)

Comment: You don't have to `.ToString()` a `string`; it's already a `string`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example you use an automatic property. An automatic property has an extra hidden field, the backing field. This field is of the same type as the property, in your case a string.

Inside this property the code will not call `ToString()` since the backing field is already of type `string`.

`Console.WriteLine` has many overloads. One of these overloads accepts a parameter of type `string`. So inside `Console.WriteLine` there is no need to call `ToString()`, because the parameter is already of that type.

In short: No `ToString()` will be called anywhere.

If, on the other hand, the property was not an automatic property and the field (or fields) behind it are of another type, then they would need to be converted to a string, using `ToString()`.

If, on the other hand, another overload of `Console.WriteLine` was called, where the parameter was of type `object`, than `WriteLine` has to call `ToString()` at some point.

Comment: The wording in your second to last "paragraph" makes it sound like `ToString()` is never needed with an automatic property. `ToString()` would be called in any case where the type was not already `String`.

Comment: @Cemafor: Any automatic property will not call any conversion methods whatsoever, because the backing field is always of the same type as the property. Why convert the data if they are of the same type. That would only consume performance.

Comment: I mean in the case where `Console.WriteLine(whatHappens);` is being called, which I assume is where the question of calling `ToString()` arises.

Comment: @Cemafor: A convert operation only occurs if data goes from one type to another type. In your example, it does not.

Comment: I'm saying if your property is of type `double`, for example. When you call `Console.WriteLine(thisIsADouble);`, the `WriteLine` function will call thisIsADouble.ToString() internally. `WriteLine` needs some way of geting the string representation of anything it wants to write out. So if it's not a `String` already, It will call the `ToString()` function to get it.

Comment: @Cemafor: Yes, your are correct. When the property is a double WriteLine would have to convert it into a string, calling ToString().